# What would be the expression, true or false

Tags: c

```
uint8_t ui8 = 255;
ui8 == (int16_t)-1
```

As far as I understand the [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1):

> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, then the operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

`ui8` would be converted/promoted to int16_t and then it's arithmetic value would be `-1`. Unfortunately the compiler I am using says I am not right.

Comment: If you cast `uint8` to `int16` the value 255 is 255.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

variable `ui8`, with value `255` will be converted to type `int` for the comparison, where it still has value `255`.

Value `(int16_t)-1` will also be converted to type `int`, where it still has value `-1`.

`255` compared against `-1` is `false`.

Comment: This is an over-simplification. If `int` is 16 bits on the particular machine, then yes the `ui8` will get converted to `int16_t`. But because of integer promotion, and not because of balancing between the operands, as your answer implies. And in case `int` is 32 bits, your answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Lundin: The logic may be incorrect, but the conclusion isn't, and for sound reasons. Both values (-1 and 255) are within the range of the promoted type.

Comment: @MSalters I just wanted to clarify that the promotion of the `uint8_t` operand doesn't depend on type of the `int16_t` operand. Lots of C programmers are confused about the implicit type promotion rules. Anyway, the answer has been corrected by the poster now, so all is well.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever a `uint8_t` or any other small integer type is used as part of an expression, it gets integer promoted to type `int`. The same goes for `int16_t`, in case `int` is larger than 16 bits.

So your code is guaranteed to be equal to:

`(int)255 == (int)-1`

which is always false.

Because of integer promotions, both operands are already of the same type, so no balancing between operands takes place.

Answer (score 1):

> ui8 would be converted/promoted to int16_t and then it's arithmetic value would be -1.

Yes , type of `ui8` will be converted/promoted .(As mentioned by Lundin Sir !! in comment ) Its because of `integer promotion` thus `ui8` will be promoted to type `int16_t` in case `int` is `16 bit` but if on your machine `int` is larger than `16 bit` then both will be promoted to `int`.

And as per your quote from standards , it says about type not the values. So `ui8` will retain its value i.e `255`.

And thus -

```
  ui8==(int16_t)-1 // may be (int)u8==(int)-1 depends on size of int on you machine
```

results in `false`.

Comment: This is an over-simplification. If int is 16 bits on the particular machine, then yes the ui8 will get converted to int16_t. But because of integer promotion, and not because of balancing between the operands, as your answer implies. And in case int is 32 bits, your answer is incorrect.